# HealthKit Error "Failed to find some objects for deletion" when attempting to delete HKWorkout

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I've had a long running problem of receiving this error from HealthKit when attempting to "modify" an `HKWorkout` by (1) copying an existing workout (2) updating the metadata (3) deleting the "old" workout (selectedWorkout in my code below) then (4) saving the new modified workout.  98% of the time this code works flawlessly, however 2% of the time I will get this error and I end up with duplicate workouts.  Am I doing anything wrong?

As an aside I really wish HealthKit would let us modify data so that this dance wasn't necessary.

```
class func updateMetadataDeleteOldAndSaveNewWorkout(selectedWorkout: HKWorkout, handler: @escaping (Bool,WorkoutManagerError? ) -> Void) {   

    //configure metadata   

    //  Create a new workout with the old workout's fields and new edited metadata object
                let newWorkout = HKWorkout(activityType: selectedWorkout.workoutActivityType, start: selectedWorkout.startDate, end: selectedWorkout.endDate, duration: selectedWorkout.duration, totalEnergyBurned: selectedWorkout.totalEnergyBurned, totalDistance: selectedWorkout.totalDistance, metadata: metadata)

                // Delete the old workout
                HealthStoreSingleton.sharedInstance.healthStore.delete(selectedWorkout, withCompletion: { (success, error) in

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                     if let unwrappedError = error  {
                         handler(false, WorkoutManagerError.deleteError(unwrappedError.localizedDescription))
                        return 
                     }
                    }

                    //  When delete was successful save the new workout
                    HealthStoreSingleton.sharedInstance.healthStore.save(newWorkout) { success, error in

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let unwrappedError = error {
                                handler(false, WorkoutManagerError.saveError(unwrappedError.localizedDescription))
                                return 
                            }

                            if success {

                                handler(true, nil)
                                return 
                            } else {
                                  handler(false, WorkoutManagerError.saveError("\(String(describing: error))"))
                                  return 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem, My code is okay. In such case, HealthKit does not allow all data to be deleted. Only you can delete the data which are saved from your app.